# How can I pull the values of an XML File setup like this?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 (C#, WinForms)

I can't seem to find a decent tutorial or example anywhere on how to pull data from odd tags such as these. Most of them only have a value between simple tags. Is there an easy way to do this?

The XML File is setup like so:

```
<root>
  <object type="Item">
      <field name="id">12345</field>
      <field name="name">Item Name</field>
      <field name="description">Item Description</field>
      <field name="Image">
           <object type="Graphic">
                <field name="format">PNG</field>
                <field name="width">100</field>
                <field name="height">200</field>
           </object>
      </field>
  </object>
</root>
```

How can I pop the values of each of these nodes and put them into a textbox for each?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with XPathNavigator.
Load xml to a XmlDocument a then create a XPathNavigator to get the values

```
var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
var nav = xDoc.CreateNavigator();
//Goes to root
nav.MoveToFirstChild();
//Goes to first elements
nav.MoveToFirstChild();

//Goes to first elements in node - can be recursive
nav.MoveToFirstChild();
do
{
    //For inner object better in recursive function if(nav.HasChildren) nav.MoveToFirstChild()
    //Be carefull to check if children is only the text of element
    var name = nav.GetAttribute("name","");
    var val = nav.Value;
} while (nav.MoveToNext());
```

Comment: worked perfectly for the first item, i'll play with this some tomorrow to see if i can't get it to pull every item in the list along with it's child object (the image). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `XmlReader` Object from the `System.Xml` package of .NET

So you can do something like

```
string xmlString = File.ReadAllText(C:\Some\Directory\File.xml);
XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString));
reader.ReadToFollowing("field");
```

Then just compare the attribute and put the value for each attribute in a variable or an array, depending on how you will implement the `XmlReader`

You can read more from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my previous post was inaccurate & didn't need to be so complicated.

Here's the simpler XLINQ version:

```
void Main()
{
    var xml = @"<root>
      <object type=""Item"">
          <field name=""id"">12345</field>
          <field name=""name"">Item Name</field>
          <field name=""description"">Item Description</field>
          <field name=""Image"">
               <object type=""Graphic"">
                    <field name=""format"">PNG</field>
                    <field name=""width"">100</field>
                    <field name=""height"">200</field>
               </object>
          </field>
      </object>
    </root>";

    var rdr = new StringReader(xml);
    var elem = XElement.Load(rdr);
    var result = elem.Descendants("field").Select(e => 
        new Tuple<string, string>(e.Attribute("name").Value, e.Value)).ToList();
}
```

Result:

[image]